# Java Inheritance Question - How to change the properties of every sub class that is required in super

Tags: java, inheritance

I am new to java inheritance and I have been trying to create a game.

This game has a game object abstract class and I created a `Enemy` class that extends it. Now I want **to add multiple types of enemies to extend** `Enemy`. I am trying to find **the most efficient way to do this** however I can not figure out how to give the sub class `final` properties that can be used by the `super` if that makes sense. *For instance*, I want all the enemies to have a speed in the X direction and the Y direction, but I want each type of enemy to have their own.

The way I have it now, is basically pointless because even if I create an `FastEnemy`, I have to put it all in the constructor when I create the object. This is probably really simple, I am just new and never ran into this before.

```java
package first.Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;


public class Enemy extends GameObject{

    private Handler handler;
    private Color c; 
    private int eWidth, eHeight, speedX, speedY, x, y;

    public Enemy(int x, int y, int eWidth, int eHeight, int speedX, int speedY, Color c, ID id, Handler handler)
    {
        super(x, y, id);

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.id = ID.Enemy;
        this.c = c;
        this.eWidth = eWidth;
        this.eHeight = eHeight;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, eWidth, eHeight);
    }

    public void tick()
    {
        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;

        if(y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 48) speedY *= -1; //What can I do instead of 48?
        if(x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 32) speedX *= -1;

        handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, c, eWidth, eHeight, 0.03f, handler));
    }

    public void render(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(x, y, eWidth, eHeight);
    }
}
```

```java
package first.Game;

import java.awt.Color;

public class FastEnemy extends Enemy{


    public FastEnemy(int x, int y, int eWidth, int eHeight, int speedX, int speedY, Color c, ID id, Handler handler)
    {

        super(x, y, eWidth, eHeight, speedX, speedY, c, id, handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is *[..]required in the super* then you have to pass it. Do you not want each subclass calling `super(x, y, id)`?

Comment: I want each subclass to have their own size(ewidth, eheight), speed in x and y directions(speedx, speedy), and their own Color(c). So if I understand inheritance correctly, I am thinking that all enemies need those things so I can put them all in the enemy constructor, but then I am not sure how to update those things in the subclasses. If that makes sense. But I need x, y, id, because that is in Enemy which is in GameObject

Comment: As far as I can see, you have already achieved that by passing them to `FastEnemy` constructor. From there it is passed on to the abstract class. Do you want it to be updated after construction?

Comment: `handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(WIDTH - 64), r.nextInt(HEIGHT - 64), 16, 16, 5, 5, Color.red, ID.Enemy, handler));` This is what I have to do right now. But if I have to give them all those sizes everytime… then really there is no difference between the different types of enemies. It is just an enemy that I have to manually change everytime I create one. So this is the problem I am confused on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment

> `handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(WIDTH - 64), r.nextInt(HEIGHT - 64), 16, 16, 5, 5, Color.red, ID.Enemy, handler));` This is what I have to do right now. But if I have to give them all those sizes everytime… then really there is no difference between the different types of enemies. It is just an enemy that I have to manually change everytime I create one.

If the values of the speed and size are constants and the value depends on an enemy type, it can be placed within the class itself. You take only the other variables as parameters.

```
public class FastEnemy extends Enemy {

    public FastEnemy(int x, int y, Color c, ID id, Handler handler)
    {

        super(x, y, 16, 16, 5, 5, c, id, handler);
    }
}
```

You can initialize the `Color` and `ID` too in the same way (if they are constants)

Comment: AHHHHH this is it. Thank you! I thought I had to keep the FastEnemy() constructor same as Enemy but its just the super that needs to stay the same. That makes much more sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

There are many things you can do. One thing you can do is make whatever variable you want updated in the objects constructor method. For example, in the constructor method for the fast enemy, you can update the speed to 5 if the normal speed is something like 3. Also, since methods are overridden, you can override a get method for whatever variable you want, and each object returns its unique value through the get method.

I'm assuming that you don't know method overriding. It is a pretty complicated subject, but here is the basic run-down: If there is one object extending another object, if the parent class has one object that the child class wants to do differently, it can just declare that method in its own class with everything the same except the method body. If you didn't get it, here is an example.

This is just basic pseudo code, it's not really following the exact syntax of java.

```
class Tree {
    public void print() {
        print "I am a tree"
    }
}
```

Then there is this other class that extends it.

```
class BirchTree {
    // Note the public void is the same. You can somewhat modify that, but thats a little more complicated.
    public void print() {
        print "I am a birch tree"
    }
}
```

So, it another class hold a Tree object, but it is really a birch tree, when they call the print method, instead of printing "I am a tree," it prints "I am a birch tree."

If you don't want that, you can use the other variation. In the constructor method, you can set that variable to whatever you want.

```
class Tree extends BiggerTree {
    int height;

    Tree(int height) {
        // If the user created this object expecting it to be something else, then just the parameter.
        height = 10; // If a bigger tree's height is usually 15 or something.
        this.height = height;
    }
```

Hope this made sense.

Comment: So I would like to just update the variables like your example 5 from 3 or whatever. The problem is I don't know how. I know that is probably stupid question. I have just started inheritance stuff this week, and I have tried looking at some examples but I am still stuck. I just dont know how to update the speed for each type of enemy without having to input a speed every time I create an instance of that object. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: But in my case I would have to override every method then. So doesn't that just make the code longer?

Comment: If you don't want that, you can use the other variation. In the constructor method, you can set that variable to whatever you want. I edited my answer.

Comment: I see what you mean. You did close to the other guy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put the speed in the constructor every time you could just have multiple classes (assuming that you want static speeds for each speed type of enemy)?

```
public class Enemy
{

private Handler handler;
private Color c; 
private int eWidth, eHeight, speedX, speedY, x, y;


public Enemy(int x, int y, int eWidth, int eHeight, int speedX, int speedY, Color c, 
ID id, Handler handler)
{

    super(x,y,id);

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.c = c;
    this.eWidth = eWidth;
    this.eHeight = eHeight;
    this.handler = handler;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
}

public int getSpeedY() //test function 
{
    return this.speedY;
}

}

public class FastEnemy extends Enemy
{


    public FastEnemy(int x, int y, int eWidth, int eHeight, Color c, ID id, Handler 
handler)
    {

        super(x, y, eWidth, eHeight, 5,5,c,id,handler); //sets a static value for 
                                                        //speed and passes it to the 
                                                        //super function for enemy 


    }

}

public class NormalEnemy extends Enemy
{


    public NormalEnemy(int x, int y, int eWidth, int eHeight,Color c, ID id, Handler 
handler)
    {

        super(x, y, eWidth, eHeight, 3,3, c, id, handler);

    }

}

public class SlowEnemy extends Enemy
{

    public SlowEnemy(int x, int y, int eWidth,int eHeight,Color c, ID id, Handler 
handler)
    {
        super(x,y,eWidth,eHeight,1,1,c,id,handler);
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Main m = new Main();

    FastEnemy newEnemy = m.new FastEnemy(1,2,4,4,c,id,handler); //just a test 
    instance

    SlowEnemy otherEnemy = m.new SlowEnemy(1,2,3,3,c,id,handler); //just a test 
    instance

    System.out.println(otherEnemy.getSpeedY()); //just a test print
}
}
```

But if you want to make a custom speed for *every* enemy, then your best bet is just using constructors every time.

Since you seem to be annoyed with having to manually input for stuff every time you make an enemy, I would just make a bunch of set variables or classes related to size, speed, etc. But the more custom you want to make your enemies, the more stuff you're gonna have to do manually.

Comment: Yeah I would like every type of enemy to have their own speed. I was thinking maybe I could just update speed in each enemy type but then when I call it in my Game class like `handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(WIDTH - 64), r.nextInt(HEIGHT - 64), 16, 16, 5, 5, Color.red, ID.Enemy, handler));` if I had those values as variables it would not know that variable correct? Maybe I could make them static? But then I would have so many variables.